# How to make dataframe out of lists?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, wikipedia

I'm working on creating a dataframe with information from wikipedia pages. 1905 wikipedia pages to be exact. I'm using the following function with a list of page titles I have, under the dataframe portalAcadie_titles.

Here are a few of the titles I'm looking to extract information from:

*"10e Convention nationale acadienne", "11e Convention nationale acadienne", 
"12e Convention nationale acadienne", "13e Convention nationale acadienne", 
"14e Convention nationale acadienne", "15e Convention nationale acadienne", 
"16e Convention nationale acadienne", "1755 (groupe)", "1re Convention nationale acadienne", 
"2e Convention nationale acadienne", "33e finale des Jeux de l'Acadie", 
"3e Convention nationale acadienne", "4e Convention nationale acadienne", 
"5e Convention nationale acadienne", "6e Convention nationale acadienne", 
"7e Convention nationale acadienne", "8e Convention nationale acadienne", 
"9e Convention nationale acadienne", "Abbé Lanteigne", "Abel Leblanc", 
"Aberdeen (Nouvelle-Écosse", "Aboiteau", "Abrams-Village"*

See the code bellow:

```
library(WikipediR)
pageInfo_fun <- function(portalAcadie_titles){
  page_info(language = "fr", 
            project = "wikipedia", 
            page = portalAcadie_titles,
            properties = c("url"),
            clean_response = T, Sys.sleep(0.0001))}

pageInfo_data <- apply(portalAcadie_titles,1, pageInfo_fun)
```

I'm trying to get this to a dataframe with each observation being a page with its properties as variables. But it gives me a list of characteristic for each page, within a list of all the pages.

A simple

```
pageInfo_df <- data.frame(pageInfo_data)
```

gives me 1 observation with all of the caracteristics to every page side by side. I have 1 observation with 24 773 variables.

My question is: how can i make each page as an observation, with the caracteristics as variables?

Comment: Can you share first few wikipedia pages ? `dput(head(portalAcadie_titles))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah yes of course! It gave me the following results (they're from the french wikipedia).
structure(list(Title = structure(c(9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L
), .Label = c("10e Convention nationale acadienne", "11e Convention nationale acadienne", 
"12e Convention nationale acadienne", "13e Convention nationale acadienne", 
"14e Convention nationale acadienne", "15e Convention nationale acadienne")

Comment: Using the Tidyverse `purrr` library, `map_dfr(pageInfo_data, ~flatten(.))` seems to produce an observation for each page.

Comment: @drf it worked exactly as I wanted!! Thank you! I would suggest you write up an answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tidyverse `purrr` package can be used to produce the desired output:

```
map_dfr(pageInfo_data, ~flatten(.))
```

This approach flattens the output for each observation, and maps the output of each to a dataframe row.

Answer (score 1):

`pageInfo_fun` currently returns a nested list, if you convert the function to return a dataframe instead then you can use `lapply` for every page and `rbind` them together to form one dataframe.

```
library(WikipediR)

pageInfo_fun <- function(portalAcadie_titles){
  as.data.frame(page_info(language = "fr", 
         project = "wikipedia", 
         page = portalAcadie_titles,
         properties = c("url"),
         clean_response = T, Sys.sleep(0.0001)))
}

x <- c("10e Convention nationale acadienne", "11e Convention nationale acadienne")
do.call(rbind, lapply(x, pageInfo_fun))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Since I have 1905 pages to combine, will I need to enter each one in the second to last row?

Comment: @JudithBourque No, I used it only for my testing purposes. I am guessing you already have them in `portalAcadie_titles`, use that instead of `x`.

Comment: Right! I'm still new to R so thanks for the reminder.